# Count ng-hide elements

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using PHP to loop through the data that requires to be filtered on my page and then using `ng-hide` to hide and show data based on the filter array in my controller.

However, when I try and create a number of results script it seems it is only getting the number of the results previously shown (so if I start with 3, and click something that shows only 2 results, results shown will say 3).

```
    /* Watch for changes in the Filter JSON array. */
    $scope.$watchCollection('Filter', function(){
       $scope.filterResults = $(".compContOuter").not(".ng-hide").length;
    });

    /* Get the results shown upon page load */
    $scope.filterResults = $(".compContOuter").not(".ng-hide").length;
```

There is a span tag that has `ng-bind='filterResults'` to show the length of the divs.

**Example Image:**

[image]

Comment: Please don't use DOM selectors in your controller, instead use objects

Comment: Can you elaborate why, @devqon?

Comment: For many reasons like : you are not using the binding power of angular which will resolve easily your problem; you need to call a $digest when you are dealing with the dom; if tomorrow you use ng-if, you will have to update your controller (maintenance issue); using too much $watchers can slow your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//if you play with watch then for you have to destroy it also so it will 
//make performance boost and make angular digest life cycle easy..hope it 
//make sense

var filterWatch = $scope.$watchCollection('Filter', function(){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.filterResults = $(".compContOuter").not(".ng-hide").length;
    });
});

//Destroy watch here
$scope.$on('$destroy', filterWatch);
```

Comment: Instead of $timeout, I used $interval and resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty way:
Normally these kind of delay issues can be fixed by adding a $timeout around your code, like

```
$scope.$watchCollection('Filter', function(){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.filterResults = $(".compContOuter").not(".ng-hide").length;
    });
});
```

What I'm not understand is, you already have the number inside the bracket of each filter, can't that be assigned to the title?

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you should not do this in your controller and you should avoid using jQuery all together.

But your problem is caused by the `$scope` not being updated. You could add `$scope.$applyAsync()` to your `$watchCollection` callback. For example:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('Filter', () => {
   $scope.filterResults = $(".compContOuter").not(".ng-hide").length;
   $scope.$applyAsync();
});
```

This will force a digest cycle on the $scope.

Comment: I am not sure then what the problem might be.